# netmiko key authentication failure

Tags: netmiko

Seeing some issue with netmiko KEY authentication with N7K.

Python 3.8.10, netmiko 4.1.2.

Firstly tried on N9K without any issue, command can be sent after get the connection.

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from netmiko import ConnectHandler
>>> n9k = {"device_type": "cisco_nxos", "host": "10.1.1.10", "username": "admin", "use_keys": True,"key_file":"~/.ssh/id_rsa", "passphrase": "Cisco123"}
>>> target_con = ConnectHandler(**n9k)
```

Hit the issue when trying the connection to a N7K switch.

```
>>> n7k = {"device_type": "cisco_nxos", "host": "10.1.1.20", "username": "admin", "use_keys": True,"key_file":"~/.ssh/id_rsa", "passphrase": "Cisco123"}
>>> target_con = ConnectHandler(**n7k)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1046, in establish_connection
    self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 435, in connect
    self._auth(
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 771, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 747, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_publickey(username, key)
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1635, in auth_publickey
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 259, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 365, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 439, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 444, in _open
    self.establish_connection()
  File "/home/admin/netmiko_test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1083, in establish_connection
    raise NetmikoAuthenticationException(msg)
netmiko.exceptions.NetmikoAuthenticationException: Authentication to device failed.

Common causes of this problem are:
1. Invalid username and password
2. Incorrect SSH-key file
3. Connecting to the wrong device

Device settings: cisco_nxos 10.1.1.20:22


Authentication failed.
>>>
```

The username and ssh key have been validated. All work well if using username/password instead.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue when studying another similar paramiko problem.
The N9K node I tested against with uses openssh 8.3, thus it is rsa-sha2-256.
The N7K node uses openssh5.9 which is ssh-sha1.
That makes a difference as netmiko seems don't like ssh-sha1 by default.
Adding `disabled_algorithms = {'pubkeys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']}` to ConnectHandler fixed the issue.